# UGC not being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create user-generated posts. I know that the posts are being created in the 
db, but are not displaying. Terminal puts:

```
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (18.4ms)  INSERT INTO "events" ("content", "created_at", "updated_at",
    "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "Test post."], ["created_at",
    Sat, 15 Oct 2011 06:36:49 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at",
    Sat, 15 Oct 2011 06:36:49 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/events
Started GET "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Oct 15 00:36:49 -0600 2011
  Processing by EventsController#show as HTML
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Event without an ID):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:22:in `show'
```

Saying the same thing, but my app gives me the same error:

```
Couldn't find Event without an ID
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:22:in `show'
```

Is this a problem with my Events_Controller method "show":

```
def show
  @title  = "Your Events"
  @event  = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

Or a routine issue? I'm trying to display an index of all events created.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The `INSERT INTO "events" ...` query on your second line above isn't a valid SQL query. Where is this being generated? The error "Couldn't find Event without an ID" means that you're calling `Event.find` without an ID or the value you're passing to it is `nil`. What does `params` contain at this time?

Comment: What url do you enter in your browser? Or how do you redirect from create action?

Comment: @Jordan: params contains (as far as I know) content, created_at, updated_at, user_id for the events class. Sorry, I'm beginning RoR, have to start somewhere.

Comment: @apneadiving, if success redirect_to events_path else render_new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EventsController on [line 13](https://github.com/latinforadapt/grmbly_app/blob/master/app/controllers/events_controller.rb#L13) you have:

```
redirect_to events_path
```

I believe this corresponds to the sixth line in your log above ("`Redirected to http://localhost:3000/events`").

When you use `redirect_to`, however, it initiates a new `GET` request, and as you did not specify any parameters `params` is consequently empty. That's why `params[:id]` is `nil` and `Event.find(params[:id])` throws the error you're seeing.

Instead of using `redirect_to`, are you sure you shouldn't be using `render :action => :show` or `render :action => :index`? Unlike `redirect_to`, `render` does not initiate a new request, it merely renders the specified view, but within the current context (where, in your case, `@event` is already defined.

For more information on `render` vs. `redirect_to` read the [Rails Guide on Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), section 2 in particular.

Comment: Thank you for the article I will study this while I look into RoR more. I replaced with render :action => :show and it displays it the post, but doesn't save it. Render :action => :index gives me an error with undefined method `model_name' :4, which is <%= render @events %>. I will look into why these aren't saving, but at least they are displaying with render :action => show.